# Почему не ставится дефис в приложении "труженик ученый"?

Tags: орфография

Вот предложение: "И дань души своей влюбленной несут Байкалу с давных лет рыбак, и труженик ученый, и живописец, и поэт". Но в книжке не поставлено тире!

Answer (score 1):

В вашем примере слово *ученый* - главное, определяемое, а слово *труженик* - приложение.
В Правилах русской орфографии и пунктуации под ред. Лопатина говорится, что 
**через дефис пишутся** сочетания с однословными приложениями, предшествующими определяемому слову, если приложения носят оценочный характер, напр.: старик-отец, красавица-дочка, умница-сын, герой-лётчик, мудрец-писатель, проказница-мартышка, самодурка-мачеха, *трудяга-следователь*, профан-редактор, пройдоха-управляющий. 
Думаю, слово *труженик* имеет оценочное значение(положительная коннотация). Так что дефис здесь нужен.

Answer (score 0):

Контекст дайте. Может быть, и надо поставить. 
Если в двух словах, то зависит от того, на какое слово смысловое ударение падает.

Answer (score 0):

А есть и такое мнение.
Выражение "красавец мужчина" (и иные подобные выражения) пишется без дефиса, т.к. "красавец" находится перед "мужчина" (красивый мужчина). Но "мужчина-красавец".